# undefined value from foreach loop

Tags: javascript

can someone explain why I am getting undefined in my loop? I am trying to run a loop that lets me know if its true if i've watched something as well as the rating. What am I doing wrong?

```
var films = [

{
    movie: "fast and the furious",
    rating: 4,
    seen: true
},
{
    movie:"13 reasons why",
    rating: 5,
    seen: true


}, 
{
    movie:"beaty and the beast",
    rating: 4,
    seen: false
}

];

films.forEach(function(movie){
var result = "You have ";
if(movie.seen) {
    result += "watched ";
} 
else{
    result += "not seen ";
}
result += "\"" + films.movie + "\" - ";
result += films.rating + " stars";

console.log(result);

});
```

Comment: Should be `movie.movie` and `movie.rating`.

Comment: you're selecting each item as `movie` inside forEach, if you want to access an item's properties, you'll use `movie` not `films`

Answer (score 1):

You should access the element, not the array, in your iterator function:

```
films.forEach(function(movie) {
  var result = "You have ";
  if (movie.seen) {
    result += "watched ";
  } else {
    result += "not seen ";
  }
  result += "\"" + movie.movie + "\" - ";
  result += movie.rating + " stars";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You passing a movie parameter in your function. you should use this for result.

```js
var films = [

{
    movie: "fast and the furious",
    rating: 4,
    seen: true
},
{
    movie:"13 reasons why",
    rating: 5,
    seen: true


}, 
{
    movie:"beaty and the beast",
    rating: 4,
    seen: false
}

];

films.forEach(function(movie){
var result = "You have ";
if(movie.seen==true) {
    result += "watched ";
}else{
    result += "not seen ";
}
result += "\"" + movie.movie + "\" - ";
result += movie.rating + " stars";

console.log(result);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var films = [

{
    movie: "fast and the furious",
    rating: 4,
    seen: true
},
{
    movie:"13 reasons why",
    rating: 5,
    seen: true


}, 
{
    movie:"beaty and the beast",
    rating: 4,
    seen: false
}

];


films.forEach(function(film){
var result = "You have ";
if(film.seen) {
    result += "watched ";
} 
else{
    result += "not seen ";
}
result += "\"" + film.movie + "\" - ";
result += film.rating + " stars";

console.log(result);

});
```

Use some other variable to enter `foreach` and use same variable to read properties.

Comment: Hey so all you did was change the name of my foreach function parameter from movie to film and thats it did you edit any other code? So I kept getting an undefined method because I also have an object with movie in it right? Just trying to get a better understanding .

Comment: Actually there was 2 problem .. first is the movie object passed .. and second ... YOu are reading moviename and starts from the array itself `movies.stars` which is invalid .. you either need `movies[key].stars` or forEach object with `movie.star`